How do I fix this minimax algorithm for Mancala?
As a challenge I've decided to try and code a minimax algorithm without using the internet. I haven't even written the AI class, but I have built a Node class and a search ahead method. The problem I'm running into is that all of the values I'm getting are poorly weighed towards the first player, which makes no sense.
I've even tried playing through some of the branches myself on a physical board to make sure I'm not going crazy, and a lot of the values just aren't matching up. I'd love to know what I'm screwing up, this has been driving me crazy!
When I included a print statement in my search ahead that prints the values of all successive moves, and then input a depth greater than 3, for some reason all of the returned values are negative.
Here's some example values when I check the node1 with a depth of 3:
pocket 8: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
pocket 9: [0, -1, -1, -1, -1]
pocket 10: [-1, -1, -2, -2, -2]
pocket 11: [-1, -1, -2, -2, -2]
pocket 12: [-8, -1, -2, -2, -2]
pocket 13: [-1, -3, -2, -2, -2]
pocket 1: [-1, -1, -2, -2, -8, -3].

When I actually play the game, the resulting values are different than what search ahead seems to think they are(where the values represent the difference between the bottom players score and the top players score)
import copy
import random
import numpy

    
class Board():
    def __init__(self,turn,position,pockets,game_state):
        self.turn=turn
        self.position=position
        self.pockets=pockets
        self.game_state=game_state

    def make_pieces(self):
        for i in range(1,7):
            self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]=4

        for i in range(8,14):
            self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]=4
        self.pockets["pocket_7"]=0
        self.pockets["pocket_14"]=0


    def move_pieces(self):
        starting_position=self.position
        current_position=self.position
        pieces_in_pocket=self.pockets[f"pocket_{self.position}"]
        pieces_dropped=0
        move_again="False"
        valid_move="True"
        board_values=[valid_move,move_again]

        if starting_position==7 or starting_position==14:
            valid_move="False"
            move_again="False"
            board_values=[valid_move,move_again]
            return board_values

        elif self.turn=="top" and starting_position in range(1,8):
            valid_move="False"
            move_again="False"
            board_values=[valid_move,move_again]
            return board_values

        elif self.turn=="bottom" and starting_position in range(8,15):
            valid_move="False"
            move_again="True"
            board_values=[valid_move,move_again]
            return board_values
        else:
            valid_move="True"
            if self.pockets[f"pocket_{self.position}"]==0:
                valid_move="False"
                final_move=current_position
                move_again="False"
                board_values=[valid_move,move_again]
                return board_values
            else:
                for i in range(0,pieces_in_pocket):
                    if current_position==13 and self.turn=="bottom":
                        current_position=0
                    if current_position==6 and self.turn=="top":
                        current_position=7
                    if current_position==14 and self.turn=="top":
                        current_position=0
                    self.pockets[f"pocket_{current_position+1}"]+=1
                    self.pockets[f"pocket_{starting_position}"]-=1
                    pieces_in_pocket-=1
                    pieces_dropped+=1
                    current_position+=1
                    final_move=current_position

            if final_move==7 and self.turn=="bottom":
                move_again="True"
            elif final_move==14 and self.turn=="top":
                move_again="True"
            else:
                move_again="False"
            for i in range(1,7):
                if final_move==i and self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]==1 and self.turn=="bottom":
                    if self.pockets[f"pocket_{14-i}"]==0:
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_7"]=self.pockets[f"pocket_7"]
                    else:
                        self.pockets["pocket_7"]=self.pockets["pocket_7"]+self.pockets[f"pocket_{14-i}"]
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_{14-i}"]=0
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_7"]=self.pockets[f"pocket_7"]+self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]=0
            for i in range(8,14):
                if final_move==i and self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]==1 and self.turn=="top":
                    if self.pockets[f"pocket_{14-i}"]==0:
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_14"]=self.pockets[f"pocket_14"]
                    else:
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_14"]=self.pockets["pocket_14"]+self.pockets[f"pocket_{14-i}"]
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_{14-i}"]=0
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_14"]=self.pockets["pocket_14"]+self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]
                        self.pockets[f"pocket_{i}"]=0
            board_values=[valid_move,move_again]
        return board_values

class Node():
    def __init__(self,game_state,pocket,children,depth,values,parent):
        self.game_state=game_state
        self.pocket=pocket
        self.children=children
        self.depth=depth
        self.values=values
        self.parent=parent

    def search_ahead(self):
        if self.depth==1:
            test_board=copy.deepcopy(self.game_state)
            test_board.position=self.pocket
            useful_list=test_board.move_pieces()
            pocket_7=test_board.pockets["pocket_7"]
            pocket_14=test_board.pockets["pocket_14"]
            value=pocket_7-pocket_14
            if useful_list[0]=="False" and self.parent==None:
                return None
            elif useful_list[0]=="False" and self.parent!=None:
                return None
            elif useful_list[0]=="True" and self.parent!=None:
                self.parent.values.append(value)
            elif useful_list[0]=="True" and self.parent==None:
                self.values.append(value)
    
        elif self.depth!=1:
            test_board=copy.deepcopy(self.game_state)
            test_board.position=self.pocket
            useful_list=test_board.move_pieces()
            if useful_list[0]=="False" and self.parent==None:
                self.values="Invalid"
                return None
            elif useful_list[0]=="False" and self.parent!=None:
                return None
            if useful_list[1]=="True" and test_board.turn=="bottom":
                test_board.turn="bottom"
            elif useful_list[1]=="True" and test_board.turn=="top":
                test_board.turn="top"
            elif useful_list[1]=="False" and test_board.turn=="bottom":
                test_board.turn="top"
            elif useful_list[1]==False and test_board.turn=="top":
                test_board.turn="bottom"
            if test_board.turn=="bottom":
                condition="max"
                for i in range(1,7):
                    self.children.append(Node(test_board,i,[],(self.depth-1),[],self))
            elif test_board.turn=="top":
                condition="min"
                for i in range(8,14):
                    self.children.append(Node(test_board,i,[],(self.depth-1),[],self))
            for node in self.children:
                node.search_ahead()
            if condition=="max" and self.parent!=None:
                x=max(self.values)
                self.values=x
                self.parent.values.append(x)
            if condition=="min" and self.parent!=None:
                x=min(self.values)
                self.parent.values.append(x)
            print(self.pocket)
            print(self.values)
                

        
            


game_board=Board("bottom",1,"","")
game_board.pockets={"pocket_1":[],"pocket_2":[],"pocket_3":[],"pocket_4":[],"pocket_5":[],"pocket_6":[],"pocket_7":[],"pocket_8":[],"pocket_9":[],"pocket_10":[],"pocket_11":[],"pocket_12":[],"pocket_13":[],"pocket_14":[]}
game_board.make_pieces()
#Bottom pocket nodes
nodep1=Node(game_board,1,[],7,[],None)
nodep2=Node(game_board,2,[],1,[],None)
nodep3=Node(game_board,3,[],1,[],None)
nodep4=Node(game_board,4,[],1,[],None)
nodep5=Node(game_board,5,[],1,[],None)
nodep6=Node(game_board,6,[],1,[],None)
#Top pocket nodes
nodep8=Node(game_board,8,[],1,[],None)
nodep9=Node(game_board,9,[],1,[],None)
nodep10=Node(game_board,10,[],1,[],None)
nodep11=Node(game_board,11,[],1,[],None)
nodep12=Node(game_board,12,[],1,[],None)
nodep13=Node(game_board,13,[],1,[],None)

nodep1.search_ahead()


Can you be more specific about the problem? How does it show up? Where do you think the problem is in the code? What are you having trouble fixing?

"pocket_1", "pocket_2", "pocket_3"... that should not be a dictionary but a list. If you create nodes for each pocket, then your board should have these nodes as members. The OOP design should be refactored.

Why nodep1.search_ahead()? This seems to suggest the first player must start at the first node. Is that the rule? I thought there was some choice to make, and a player can choose any pocket on their side that is not empty.

Ah shoot I’ll try to reimplement the move pieces method without the dictionary. The nodep1 was just a test, once I implement an AI class the would search ahead in all six nodes they have control over and then make a decision.

There are some issues in your code:

The very last statement nodep1.search_ahead() seems to suggest you only allow the first player to play from the first pocket. This doesn't seem right.

Sometimes you compare with False and sometimes with "False": those are two distinctive values with a different data type. For boolean types you should use False and True, not strings.

In one case you set valid_move="False" and move_again="True". This seems inconsistent. When attempting an invalid move, why would you allow to move again?

I didn't find any code that checks for a game-over state, where you'd need to evaluate the board taking into account that all playable pockets should be emptied.

The board has an unused game_state attribute.

The pockets shouldn't be stored in a dictionary keyed by keys like "pocket_1", "pocket_2". For such enumeration you should use lists. This makes code concise and easier to read.


I didn't check further, as the way you approached it is not how I would do it. It should not be needed to create nodes. Minimax typically just plays the moves and gets the score back from the recursive call. There is no need to build a tree.
Here is a suggestion on implementing this:
Consider that the rules are the same for both players. The only difference is that they sit at the other side of the board and thus their left is the mirror of the player's left. You could avoid a lot of code duplication by actually turning the board around when the other player has to play, so in a way that the first pocket is now their first pocket, ...etc.
The score would then be a score from the viewpoint of the current player. The minimax algorithm can toggle the sign of such a score when bringing it back to the caller where the opponent is the current player.
Here is an implementation:
HOME = 6
HALF = 7
LAST = 12
SKIP = 13

class Board():
    def __init__(self, pockets=None, inverted=False):
        self.pockets = tuple(pockets or [4,4,4,4,4,4,0] * 2)
        self.inverted = inverted

    def get_valid_moves(self):
        for pocket in range(HOME):
            if self.pockets[pocket]:
                board = self.play(pocket)
                if board.inverted == self.inverted:  # Play follow-up move(s)
                    for takes, final_board in board.get_valid_moves():
                        yield [pocket, *takes], final_board
                else:
                    yield [pocket], board
    
    def play(self, pocket):
        pockets = list(self.pockets)
        drop_at = pocket
        # Distribute...
        for _ in range(pockets[pocket]):
            drop_at = (drop_at + 1) % SKIP
            pockets[drop_at] += 1
        pockets[pocket] = 0
        if drop_at == HOME:  # Can make a follow-up move
            return Board(pockets, self.inverted)  # Don't flip the board
        opposite = LAST - drop_at
        if pockets[drop_at] == 1 and pockets[opposite]: # Can capture
            pockets[HOME] += pockets[opposite] + 1
            pockets[drop_at] = pockets[opposite] = 0
        return Board(pockets[HALF:] + pockets[:HALF], not self.inverted)  # Flip the board
    
    def score(self):
        return self.pockets[HOME] - self.pockets[SKIP]

    def end_score(self):
        return sum(self.pockets[HALF:]) - sum(self.pockets[:HALF])
        
    def minimax(self, depth):
        moves = list(self.get_valid_moves())
        if not moves:  # Game over
            return self.end_score(), [], self
        if depth == 0:
            return self.score(), [], self
        depth -= 1
        best = -1000, None, None
        for takes, board in moves:
            score = -board.minimax(depth)[0]  # Flip sign of score
            if score > best[0]:
                best = score, takes, board
        return best

    def best_move(self, depth):
        return self.minimax(depth)[1]  # Index(es) of pocket(s) to start at


Thank you for your help! That makes a lot more sense. Now that I’m looking back on it I have no clue why I made some of the choices I did.
